# Why -1//2 = -1 but int(-1/2) = 0?

Tags: python

I found that `-1 // 2` is equal to -1 (Why not 0?), but `int(-1 / 2)` is equal to 0 (as I expected).
It's not the case with 1 instead of -1, so both `1 // 2` and `int(1 / 2)` is equal to 0.

Why the results are different for -1?

Comment: The operator `//` gives you the remainder of the division. Edit: floor division.

Comment: Do you understand what `//` actually does?

Comment: @afarrag No, it doesn't.

Comment: @chepner You're right. It gives floor division.

Comment: Hint: `-0.5` rounded down is __? And `0.5`? `int()` isn't necessary

Comment: @chepner, I read that it does floor division, but what then `int(n)` does? I thought it does the same

Comment: No, `int` *truncates* its argument, removing the fractional part without regard to the sign of the argument.

Comment: good job reopening an obvious duplicate and letting an answer slip in I must say...

Comment: I don't consider the linked question an obvious duplicate, as it doesn't deal with truncation at all. (For the record, I had nothing to do with closing or reopening the question.)

Comment: Yeah I know you didn't reopen :) BTW better duplicate added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the division operator `/` and the floor division operator `//` have different behavior.

The division operator `/` returns a floating-point number that represents the exact quotient of the division. In the case of `-1/2`, the quotient is `-0.5`. When you cast it to int, it rounds the number up to `0`.

The floor division operator `//` returns the quotient of the division rounded down to the nearest integer. In the case of `-1//2`, the quotient is `-1`, because `-1` divided by `2` is `-0.5`, which is rounded down to `-1`.

That's why `-1//2 = -1` and `int(-1/2) = 0` in python.

Comment: `0` is rounding *up*.

Comment: Technically, it's not rounding up, either. It's rounding *towards 0*, which is true for both positive and negative arguments. It's better not to refer to it as rounding at all, as rounding in Python treats 1/2 specially (it could round up or down depending on whether the integer part is even or odd, the so-called banker's algorithm). `int` *truncates* by discarding the fraction. (I said without regard to sign in a comment, but that's not entirely true. The sign plays a part in deciding what the integer portion is: `-0.5` is `0 - 0.5`, not `-1 + 0.5`.)